# Checkbox state change using a public enum

Tags: android, checkbox, enums

I am attempting to change the state of a check box through a checked changed listener in a baseadapter.  I would like to do this by pulling data from a separate class using a getter/setter setup where the get/set will collect the enum data.  I have getters and setters to interact with the class, but I am not sure how to do the syntax for this or if it is even a viable option.  What I need to know how to do is read check changed events back into the adapter.

```
    // set up an OnCheckedChangeListener, which
    // is called when the user toggles the status checkbox
    final CheckBox statusView = holder.statusView;

    statusView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Entered onCheckedChanged()");

            if(statusView.isChecked()){

                //not sure how to access checkbox

            }
            else{
                //unchecked, change accordingly

            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the Status object that a getter/setter would reference in another class and i would like to interact with from the baseadapter:

```
    public enum Status {
    OFF, ON
    };
    ...
    public Status getStatus() {
    return mStatus;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
    mStatus = status;
    }
```

Comment: Why create an entire secondary object to store something that's just a boolean value? Also the performance documentation for Android recommends against the use of Enum values. With newer compiler updates it has gotten better but Enums are still bloaty, https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Overhead

Comment: Its for a class assignment.  I'd not implement it like this but I can't change the code otherwise the resulting test cases would break.  I don't know how to interact with enum data in another class to manipulate a check box listener

Comment: Are you trying to load data into a list of checkboxes, read check change events back into the adapter, both? I think you might need to clarify your question as it's either too broad or doesn't have quite enough detail in it.

Comment: `CompoundButton buttonView` <-- That `buttonView` is your checkbox. `boolean isChecked` <-- That `isChecked` is the new state of that checkbox.

Comment: so your adapter is something like `MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Status>`?

Comment: Yes.  I need to interact with a status change object in another class that defines parameters of a todo object with a checkbox.

Comment: how about `ListView#setOnItemClickListener` if you don't have another item click action